# Подготовка изображений для разных разрешений экрана

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Я дизайнер и передо мной встала задача нарисовать интерфейс для Android(`320х480` и `480х800`). Ознакомился с [офф.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) документом.
Возник вопрос: я нарисовал изображения для разрешения `480х800`, можно ли мне изменить их уменьшив на 1.5 (для `320х480`) или придется перерисовывать?

Comment: имхо, странный вопрос для дизайнера, разве ты не можешь посмотреть на картинку во всех размерах и решить хорошо ли она смотрится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, конечно, не дизигнер, но я обычно рисую в максимальном разрешении - ну что нибудь не менее 1024*768, а потом спокойно масштабирую под меньшие разрешения.

**update** а еще лучше иметь векторную графику Corel/SVG тогда вообще не возникает никаких вопросов.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что векторную графику не нужно подгонять под разные экраны? достаточно просто 1 файла изображения и оно само подстроится за счет того, что это векторная графика?

Answer (score 1):

Все вам правильно выше ответили. От себя добавлю еще вот [эту ссылку](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) для обязательного прочтения

Answer (score -1):

Тогда вопрос в следующем - если ориентироваться на то, что например xhdpi - 720-1280, xxhdpi - 1280-1920, hdpi - 480-800, mdpi - 320-480... То как быть с размерами самих экранов? К примеру подготовив изображения для xhdpi - они отображаются "как нужно" на 4.7 дюймовых экранах. Но xhdpi у нас не ограничивается только 4.7 экранами, и есть размеры больше, соответственно эти же картинки на больших экранах, будут отображаться маленькими. Как быть в таком случае? Вообще не могу уловить эту "закономерность". Мне как казалось, что должны быть какие либо встроенные инструменты вроде редактора иконок, который сам подстраивает размеры под разные типы экранов.... а тут получается не пойми что.

Comment: По хорошему это надо оформлять как отдельный вопрос